# gnome3 is unreadable

Tags: ati, gnome, gnome-panel

I have a serious problem.  I have fully updated ubuntu 11.10 and I recently installed gnome3. The problem is the taskbar, and the panel button that displays the activities are unreadable. I found nothing  on the Internet. Please help. Sorry for my bad English, I'm Spanish. :D.! There is a screen capture of my pc.

[image: GNOME3 with just the default wallpaper and a blue bar on the top with unreadable text]

Comment: What happens when you change the fonts? (with gnome-tweak)

Comment: @jose Do you have a screenshot you can provide, as well as some information on your graphics setup?

Answer (score 2):

This is likely if you happen to be using the proprietary ATI Catalyst driver (fglrx), which has [a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/838577) here. You can work around it if you open the Additional Drivers tool and remove fglrx, so Ubuntu will fall back to the free radeon driver instead. This will of course impact 3D performance quite heavily, but Gnome Shell will probably work smoothly and you'll gain a prettier startup screen.